# How to get the time execution for operations in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

is there a way to read operation (or the blue node in Spark DAG) took to complete? The code is written in a way so that there's only one operation, write, and everything in between like mapPartition, fileScan, etc are in this one stage so I can't predict which operation is taking the longest.

This is a sample image I got from a website and wanted to know how much each of the blue node took. Is there a way to tell in the UI? If not, is there an alternative way?

[image: https://dzone.com/articles/reading-spark-dags]

Comment: Logs (log4j logs) show things in pretty black and white. But I would guess there is something built-in available that spares you the pain of parsing logs. Have you checked if [any of the metrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#component-instance--executor) provide required info or not?

Comment: @Kashyap thank you for this but I unfortunately have access to the spark UI and that's just how it's wired at my job. I don't have access to the log4j..

Comment: time to change jobs or tell them `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`